# Name Can Be Simplified - Visual Studio 2019 Override

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have the following line of code in my ASP.NET project:

```
    public virtual async Task<bool> Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = LoadById(id);
        using (IDbConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_conn))
        {
            cn.Open();
            /* Do Not Remove <T> Variables, its required even though the compiler notes its not required */
            var result = await cn.DeleteAsync<T>(entity);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Here is the class definition:

```
public abstract class DatabaseRepository<T> where T : class, IDatabaseModel, new()
```

Visual studio 2019 is displaying a warning that I need to remove the T variable from my DeleteAsync method because it is not needed and can be simplified. The problem is that it is needed for the extension I am using (Dapper). As soon as I remove the T reference, my code will throw a runtime exception.

From:

```
var result = await cn.DeleteAsync<T>(entity);
```

To:

```
var result = await cn.DeleteAsync(entity);
```

My first thought was to add a comment next to this line to prevent other developers form removing it. However I got to thinking that there must be some type of override I can do in the code to prevent it from showing as a warning. Some type of special comment or something that I can put above the line to prevent visual studio from displaying the message. So far I've checked online and can't find anything. I'm looking for something I can put in the code not a setting change in Visual Studio.

Comment: Is it giving that warning on the consumer call? It's likely due to the fact that the compiler can infer the type based on the type of entity, so the type annotation for the generic call is redundant.

Comment: The compiler thinks it can infer the type but it ends up getting a dynamic/object type rather then its actual type. I'll provide more code to explain. Please see my next edit.

Comment: Delete calls DeleteAsync which is a Dapper method.

Comment: What is the type returned by `LoadById` ?

Comment: No, thats not the same situation, I don't want to ignore all situations with this warning. I just want to ignore this one instance.

Comment: If you read the answer you will see that you can disable the warning for just one line.

Comment: I just added the code for LoadByID

Comment: Let us know if that dupe does not do what you want it to and I will vote to reopen.

Comment: FYI, I know there are some answers that have come up that will likely work but I'd like to keep this open briefly if someone has an idea on how to update the code without suppression to prevent the message.

Comment: When you remove the generic type parameter, is it calling the extension method with the `object predicate` parameter instead of the `T entity` parameter?

Comment: What sort of warning do you get?  Intellisense, compilation, FxCop something else?

Comment: Intellisense, your fixed worked, I marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than adding a comment, add a [SuppressMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.suppressmessageattribute?view=netframework-4.8) which will prevent the warning in the first place.

```
[SuppressMessage("Reason", "Whatever the id is", Justification="Do Not Remove <T> Variables, its required even though the compiler notes its not required")]
public virtual async Task<bool> Delete(int id)
{
    var entity = LoadById(id);
    using (IDbConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_conn))
    {
        cn.Open();
        var result = await cn.DeleteAsync<T>(entity);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried, this, it didn't work :(

Comment: How did it not work?  Compiler error?  What exactly did you put in the attribute?

Comment: Nevermind, I had the ID wrong, this worked: [SuppressMessage("Reason", "IDE0001", Justification = "Do Not Remove <T> Variables, its required even though the compiler notes its not required")]